# Hybrid auth library not working

Tags: php, facebook-social-plugins, hybridauth

I am developing a site with hybridauth library. I downloaded the library from http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/. The downloaded folder has example for Facebook integration. For the sample script to work a Facebook app id and key should be added in the config file. So i created a facebook app to get id and key and included that information in the config file of hybridauth library. Then i pointed the browser to the example script. In the example script there is a link which says 'Sign in with facebook'. When i clicked the link it shows the error 'The requested URL /hybridauth-git/hybridauth/ was not found on this server.' How could i fix the error. I am working in localhost. Is that a problem when working with Hybridauth libray.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely haven't set the config location properly

https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/blob/master/examples/facebook_integration/index.php#L5

```
$config = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../hybridauth/config.php';
```

See where you config file might be.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you host the page which is using the library,then place the library on the live server.